# jq transform - json child array to delimited string

Tags: json, jq

i want to transform the following input with jq

```
{
    "count": 1000,
    "rows": [{
            "id": 1,
            "child_id": 11,
            "childarray": ["value1", "value2"]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "child_id": 12,
            "childarray": ["value3", "value4"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Output should be:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "child_id": 11,
    "childarray": "value1, value2"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "child_id": 12,
    "childarray": "value3, value4"
  }
]
```

I use this jq filter-> "`[.rows[]]`" but don't know howto "join" the array  -> `"childarray": ["value1", "value2"]` to a comma delimited string -> "`value1, value2`"

https://jqplay.org/s/5TlSDgJnkc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` + `join` approach:

```
jq '.rows | map(.childarray |= join(", "))' input.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "child_id": 11,
    "childarray": "value1, value2"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "child_id": 12,
    "childarray": "value3, value4"
  }
]
```

---

Another alternative is:

```
jq '.rows[].childarray |= join(", ") | .rows'
```